# How to turn an output into a list

Tags: python

I'm really new to python, so I'm sorry for the low level question..

my current code is

```
x = input("lower number:")
y = input("higher number:")
a=list(range(int(x), int(y)+1))
print(a)
for i in range (int(x), int(y)+1):
    number=True
    if i==1:
        number = False
    for j in range (2, i):
        if i%j==0:
            number = False
            break
    if number:
        print(i)
```

and the output comes out like this

```
lower number:1
higher number:10
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
2
3
5
7
```

I want my output to look like [2,3,5,7] instead of the current output.

Comment: create empty list before `for`-loop - `your_list = []` , next use `your_list.append(i)` instead of `print(i)` and after `for`-loop use `print(your_list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Adding onto the answer posted by @Tigran, but with an edit**

OP wanted the output to appear as `[2,3,5,7]`, basically without spaces. So on top of the code snippet posted in his (@Tigran) answer,

```
x = input("lower number:")
y = input("higher number:")
a = list(range(int(x), int(y) + 1))
o = []

for i in range (int(x), int(y) + 1):
    number = True

    if i==1:
        number = False

    for j in range (2, i):
        if i % j ==0:
            number = False
            break
    if number:
        o.append(i)

print(o)
```

you could use the `.replace()` function. This would appear as

```
x = input("lower number:")
y = input("higher number:")
a = list(range(int(x), int(y) + 1))
o = []

for i in range (int(x), int(y) + 1):
    number = True

    if i==1:
        number = False

    for j in range (2, i):
        if i % j ==0:
            number = False
            break
    if number:
        o.append(i)

print(str(o).replace(" ", ""))
```

Note the use of `str()` to convert the data type to a string in order to remove the whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Create a list and append your numbers to it.

```
x = input("lower number:")
y = input("higher number:")
a = list(range(int(x), int(y) + 1))
o = []

for i in range (int(x), int(y) + 1):
    number = True

    if i==1:
        number = False

    for j in range (2, i):
        if i % j ==0:
            number = False
            break
    if number:
        o.append(i)

print(o)
```